# As a vim user, how do I get used to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, vim, editor

I have been a Vim user for most of my life.  I have been using Emacs with viper/vimpulse for a couple of years.  What is the best way to kick my Vi habit and achieve a reasonable level of productivity with Xcode 4 on OS X Lion?  I do not want to use an external editor since I would rather immerse myself completely in Xcode.

Comment: you can't, install http://www.macports.org/ and use vim and make ;)

Comment: I leave both opened and commant+tab is my friend. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: I've been using the [xVim plugin](https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim) for the past four months, and despite a couple bugs, I feel it's the best solution at the moment.

===

I've been faced with this dilemma for the past month, and my recent solution has been [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) (which gives you a decent amount of Vi keybindings system-wide, and works on Lion).

It's by no means an optimal solution — I'm still only 60% as productive in Xcode as I am in Vim — but it is a way to stay in Xcode and have some of the Vi functionality. Here's a link to a [recent blog post with a pic of my KeyRemap4MacBook settings](http://zachwill.posterous.com/xcode-and-vi).

Also, I've been looking into commandline scripts to build and run projects (that way I could skip Xcode and stay with Vi and the terminal — though it seems you're trying to steer clear of this). I haven't found any extraordinary solution — but I'm sure if enough of us are going through this, then someone will find a feasible solution.

Comment: I believe Apple should be the one to provide Vi bindings within the Xcode editor widget.  I am going to file a bug report here https://bugreport.apple.com/.  If enough people do this, maybe Apple will listen.  Until then, I will try hard not to type hjkl all over my code :p

Comment: @sigjuice I just filed one as well.  Hopefully they listen.  I'm tired of messing around with xVim.